# Orbeon Forms - Repeated Grid - Validation Issue

Tags: grid, orbeon

I have come across an issue where the repeated grid in my form can't be saved and throws validation errors when I use the combination of both using the plus button to add new rows and Insert above/below button to add new rows. Even though all mandatory fields are entered validation errors are coming once submit button is clicked. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Would you be able to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem, that we can run here, and attach it a response so we can look into it?

Comment: Also, which exact version of Orbeon Forms are you using?

Comment: Did you get a chance to solve this issue? If not, and if it still is on your front-burner, you'll let you know if you have feedback to our questions above.